# How to get custom HTTP Headers for a GET request in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

For a custom WordPress API endpoint, I try to receive a custom header for a GET request. I'm sending the request via JavaScript with axios:

```
let response = await axios.get('url', {
  headers: {
    '_key': 'mykey'
  }
});
```

The PHP side:

```
public function get_option( $request ) {
  $data = $request->get_header('_key');
  return $data;
}
```

The result is an empty string. The method seems to be the correct one:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/get_header/

It is not possible inside WordPress to get custom header data? Or what's the issue here?

Comment: _"The result is an empty string."_ - where is that PHP method returning _to_? Is there anything after this, that actually _outputs_ the value?

Comment: I get the return value in the variable `response` from above. And no, when returning "Hello World" for testing purposes, I get the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

function wpse_288865_featch_header() {

```
$response = wp_remote_get('https://www.amazon.com/');
$custom_header = wp_remote_retrieve_header($response, 'X-Amz-Cf-Id');

var_dump($custom_header);
exit;
```

}

add_action('init', 'wpse_288865_featch_header');